# jQuery / Javascript password validation using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to implement password validation using regex or javascript. 
unfortunately i'm a total newbie to Regex :/

the criteria are :

- minimum length: 8 characters (can be upper or lower case)
- must contain 1 special character (something like !?$%&@)
- must contain at least one number

i found the following snippet but it's missing checking for at least character of type special+number ..

```
function validPassword(password) {
    var has_letters = (/[a-zA-Z]/).test(password);
    var has_numbers = (/[0-9]/).test(password);
    var has_length = 3 <= password.length && password.length <= 30;
    return has_letters && has_numbers && has_length;
}
```

thanks

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 1):

Add one extra check:

```
function validPassword(password) {
    var has_letters = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(password);
    var has_numbers = /\d/.test(password);
    var has_special = /[!?$%&@]/.test(password);
    var has_length = (password.length >=8 && password.length <= 30);

    return has_letters && has_numbers && has_special && has_length;
}
```

However if you want a single regex to do all this then use lookaheads:

```
var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!?$%&@])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]).{8,30}$/;

var isValid = re.test(password);
```

Comment: i suppose it doesnt check for length=1 on special character and number(?)

Comment: I believe you want at least one special character? Or is it that you want exact one special character?

Comment: @Fuxi you haven't said 'number should be exactly one', you said `must contain at least one number`

Comment: @anubhava yes you were right, sorry for that .. at least number was correct

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
function validPassword(password) {

    return password.length > 8 
       && password.match( /[\d]/ ) 
        && password.split( /[\W]/ ).length == 2 ;
}
```

`password.length > 8`  checks the length should be minimum 8

`password.match( /[\d]/ )`  checks if it has at least one number

`password.split( /[\W]/ ).length == 2`  checks if it has one special character

Comment: Any line that makes you scroll horizontally to see it all is too damn long ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol hope its not too long now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below regex to validate your password:

```
var regex = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$";
```

This will check validation for Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be like this:

```
(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).*
```

**Here is the detail:**

```
(?=^.{6,}$) - String is > 5 chars
(?=.*[0-9]) - Contains a digit
(?=.*[A-Z]) - Contains an uppercase letter
(?=.*[a-z]) - Contains a lowercase letter
(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]) - A character not being alphanumeric.
```